# Работ с БД MS Access

Tags: c#

Создал БД в MS Access (таблица имеет преимущественно цифровое значение ячеек). Подключил ее при помощи dataGridView. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при выборе первой ячейки (ячейка выделяется, когда на нее щелкаешь) той или иной строки, информация с других ячеек записывались в какие - нибудь переменные?
Буду очень признателен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обработайте событие CellClick объекта DataGridView, а дальше делайте все что душе угодно. А чтобы обрабатывалось только при нажатии на первую ячейку строки, то проверяйте по какой ячейке произошел клик с помощью переменной e события CellClick. У нее есть поле ColumnIndex

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!!! Разобрался. Очень помог! Всегда приятно, когда твои вопросы находят ответ